# Передача действия над объектом

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражения

Всем доброго времени суток.
имеется мап-ка <key, Struct *>, в которой содержатся данные о пользователях.
Часть мапки указывает на nullptr в значении.
Изначально в коде везде шло обращение с проверкой результата в каждом месте обращения. Грубо говоря, так:

```
key k;
if (__arr.find(k) != __arr.end() && __arr[k])
{
    //работа с данными
}
```

Поменял сделанное: вынес отдельную функцию-геттер, которая по ключу делает проверку и возвращает структуру, если она есть в значении. Это выглядит так:

```
MyStruct *Foo::get_struct_by_id(const Key& key)
{
    if (__arr.find(key) != __arr.end() && __arr[key])
        return __arr[key];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Но теперь вижу, что для перебора всех элементов в массиве приходится получать указатель на структуру, проверять его на валидность,и потом уже выполнять операцию.

**вопрос:**
Как передать действие, которое буду совершать над объектом(экземпляром структуры), в качестве параметра?

Вижу это как-то так:

- выделяю функцию "a", которая возвращает структуру по ключу, если она существует
- создаю функцию "б", в которой происходит перебор объектов - и если объект существует, то над ним выполняется операция, которую мы передали в функцию "б" параметром.
- в коде в местах, где необходимо пробежаться по всем элементам с целью выполнения операции, вызываем функцию b с указанием параметра, в котором описываем те операции над объектом, которые хотим сделать.

Буду рад приведенному примеру кода. К слову, на языке вертится "передача лямбда-выражений", "передача функций", но не понимаю, как это сделать.

Не болейте)

Comment: Проверок вы все равно не избежите, делайте их там, где это наиболее понятно (логично), не увеличивайте сложность, внося новые сущности. В общем, следуйте [KISS-принципу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Comment: Нельзя делать идентификаторы с 2 подчёркиваниями в начале. Использование двух последовательных символов подчеркивания ( _ _ ) в начале идентификатора или одного ведущего символа подчеркивания, за которым следует заглавная буква, зарезервировано для реализаций C++ во всех областях.

Comment: Если в мапе не хранить указатели, а по значению, то и не нужно будет проверять на nullptr:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте для начала напишем вот такую воспомогательную функцию

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename F>
void apply_to(std::map<K,V*>& m, F f)
{
    for(auto& el : m) {
        if (el.second != nullptr)
            f(el.first, *el.second);
    }
}
```

функция проверяет значение в мапе на `nullptr` и если оно не нулевое, то вызывает указанную функцию (или нечто, что можно вызвать), предварительно разыменовав.

Теперь, как такое позвать.

Можно по старинке:

```
void process(int k, float v) {}
apply_to(m_data, process);
```

то есть, первым параметром мапа, вторым функция. Самое чудесное (как по мне), то функции даже не нужно знать, как там внутри сохраняются данные. совсем. Ну и указатель ушел.

Способ два.

```
std::function<void(int,float)> ff = process;
apply_to(m_data, ff);
```

`std::function`, как же без них.

Теперь пойдем в функторы, и там можно

```
struct func
{
    void operator()(int k, float f) {}
};
apply_to(m_data, func());
```

ну и классика, лямбда

```
apply_to(m_data, [](int k, float f) { std::cout << k << " " << f << "\n"; });
```

конечно, если у Вас там не просто int/float, то я бы задумался о передаче пареметров но ссылке или ссылке на константу. Но тут уже нужно глубоко в код смотреть.

Если компилятор позволяет, то на это все можно ещё навешать разных концептов или `enable_if`, но это уже следующий этап.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка лучше так.

```
MyStruct *Foo::get_struct_by_id(const Key& key)
{
    if (auto it = __arr.find(key); it != __arr.end() && *it)
        return *it;
    return nullptr;
}
```

И она эквивалентна этому

```
MyStruct *Foo::get_struct_by_id(const Key& key)
{
    if (auto it = __arr.find(key); it != __arr.end())
        return *it;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Но по любому придётся делать функции вида:

```
bool has(K);
V get(K);
V* try_get(K);
```

Без этого не обойтись.

А вообще не надо хранить указатели на структуры.

Comment: `А вообще не надо хранить указатели на структуры.` а теперь поподробнее, это ещё почему?

Comment: ручное управление памятью - игра с гранатой. Обычно все ок, но если рванет, то мало не покажется.

Comment: @こきん https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t

Comment: Как ссылка связана с тем что вы написали?

Comment: @こきん напрямую связана.